# Routing traffic from device connected via Ethernet through my machine to the internet

Tags: networking, macos, routing

I have a macOS (10.15.7) laptop connected to the internet via WiFi. The IP address of the machine is 192.168.1.2. Router: 192.168.1.1

I have an external device connected to my laptop via an ethernet cable. In the Network Preferences, I have setup USB 10/100/1000 LAN with Configure IPv4 Manually, IP address 192.168.0.101, and subnet mask 255.255.255.0. I can successfully ssh into the device, which has an IP address of 192.168.0.200. The device is running ubuntu 18.04 server.

I would like to issues commands like `apt update` on the device, but I need to be able to route traffic from it through my laptop and out to the internet via my wifi connection.

How can I do that?

What I tried was:

```
$ sudo route -n add -net 192.168.0.100/24 192.168.1.1

route: writing to routing socket: File exists
add net 192.168.0.100: gateway 192.168.1.1: File exists
```

which is probably obviously wrong for reasons I do not understand and, of course, didn't work.

I am not sure what further information would be useful, but I should be able to provide it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that the issue is on the server. You are essentially trying to use your MacOS as a router. This is only possible if the MacOS is hardwired (Connected via Ethernet) to the actual router, then the MacOS can act as a WiFi router using it's native internet sharing options. In short what you are trying to do is not possible with the MacOS to my understanding.

This is one of many articles on the topic: https://www.takecontrolbooks.com/resources/0170/site/chap24.html